# Pytorch weighted Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I'm porting a little bit complex TF2 code to Pytorch. Since TF2 does not distinguish Tensor and numpy array, it was straightforward on it. However, I feel like I came back to the TF1 era when I encountered several errors saying 'you cannot mix Tensor and numpy array here in Pytorch!'. Here is the original TF2 code:

```
def get_weighted_imgs(points, centers, imgs):
  weights = np.array([[tf.norm(p - c) for c in centers] for p in points], dtype=np.float32)
  weighted_imgs = np.array([[w * img for w, img in zip(weight, imgs)] for weight in weights])

  weights = tf.expand_dims(1 / tf.reduce_sum(weights, axis=1), axis=-1)
  weighted_imgs = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(weighted_imgs, axis=1), [len(weights), 64*64*3])

  return weights * weighted_imgs
```

And my problematic Pytorch code:

```
def get_weighted_imgs(points, centers, imgs):
  weights = torch.Tensor([[torch.norm(p - c) for c in centers] for p in points])
  weighted_imgs = torch.Tensor([[w * img for w, img in zip(weight, imgs)] for weight in weights])

  weights = torch.unsqueeze(1 / torch.sum(weights, dim=1), dim=-1)
  weighted_imgs = torch.sum(weighted_imgs, dim=1).view([len(weights), 64*64*3])

  return weights * weighted_imgs

def reproducible():
  points = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((128, 5)))
  centers = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((10, 5)))
  imgs = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((10, 64, 64, 3)))

  weighted_imgs = get_weighted_imgs(points, centers, imgs)
```

I can guarantee that there is no issue with the dimension order or shape of the tensors/arrays. The error message I got is

```
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

which comes from

```
weighted_imgs = torch.Tensor([[w * img for w, img in zip(weight, imgs)] for weight in weights])
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem? That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code. It will help others to help you. In this case, please provide inputs to function get_weighted_imgs.

Comment: I added a function to reproduce this error as you suggested :)

Comment: Great. So you have w of shape torch.Size([10]) and img of shape torch.Size([64, 64, 3]) and you multiply between them in line 2 of get_weighted_imgs. What is the behavior you expect in such case?

Comment: You understood it correctly despite of my poor explanation. I want 'weighted_imgs' to be a Tensor of shape [128, 10, 64, 64, 3] which would be summed up later along the axis=1 to become of shape [128, 64, 64, 3].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help you, but I'm not sure about your final multiplication between weights and weighted_imgs since they don't have the same shape, even after reshaping as you probably wanted. I am not sure I understood correctly your logic:

```
import torch
def get_weighted_imgs(points, centers, imgs):
  weights = torch.Tensor([[torch.norm(p - c) for c in centers] for p in points])
  
  imgs = imgs.unsqueeze(0).repeat(weights.shape[0],1,1,1,1)
  dims_to_rep = list(imgs.shape[-3:])
  weights = weights.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1,1,*dims_to_rep)
  weights /= torch.sum(weights[...,0:1,0:1,0:1],dim=1, keepdim=True)
  weighted_imgs =  torch.sum(imgs * weights, dim=1).view(weights.shape[0], -1)
  
  return weighted_imgs #weights.view(weighted_imgs.shape[0],-1) *\
         #weighted_imgs # Shapes are torch.Size([128, 122880]) and torch.Size([128, 12288])

def reproducible():
  points = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((128, 5)))
  centers = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((10, 5)))
  imgs = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((10, 64, 64, 3)))

  weighted_imgs = get_weighted_imgs(points, centers, imgs)
#Test:
reproducible()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The code runs smoothly although it doesn't seem to be the optimal one. Since my time is running out, this is the perfect one for me now. :)